# Adobe Photoshop 2020 Scripting. ApplyRadialBlur - fourth parameter (object BlurCenter)

Tags: c#, .net, photoshop, photoshop-script

I think for those who created **Interop.Photoshop.dll** there is a special place in hell.
Question. I'm trying to change the center of the RadialBlur effect in C#. But I have no idea what and how to transfer parameter there.
The definition of method says

`void ApplyRadialBlur (int Amount, Photoshop.PsRadialBlurMethod BlurMethod, Photoshop.PsRadialBlurQuality BlurQuality, [object BlurCenter])`

That is, anything can be passed to the fourth parameter. Because the object keyword is the root of all types.

In the vbs help (https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html,
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-vbs-ref-2020.pdf) it says

`[, BlurCenter]` type Number (Double) The parameter BlurCenter is the
position (unit value).

WHAT? TO ME? DO? WITH THIS? INFORMATION?

I spent several hours and so could not find a normal working description of com interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double x = 0.2;
double y = 0.2;
object[] BlurCenter = new object[2] { x, y }; 

.ApplyRadialBlur(50, PsRadialBlurMethod.psZoom, PsRadialBlurQuality.psRadialBlurBest, BlurCenter);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This code works. Why did I need to make an array of objects, if I pass numbers, it's better to find out from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about **Interop.Photoshop.dll**, but in JavaScript, the position (4th paramamater) is optional. It's just an x,y position in an array:

```
activeDocument.activeLayer.applyRadialBlur(10, RadialBlurMethod.ZOOM, RadialBlurQuality.BEST, [100,100]);
```